# Saving data from form with multiple objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Following this guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html I created a form with three entities. Patient, PatientSample and PatientOrder. When I submit the form I get an error that patient_id can not be null.

I've been trying various ways to create a new Patient object in the PatientOrderController and getting the data there then calling $entityManager->persist($patient) but was having a problem populating the new Patient object with form data.

PatientOrderType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('accession_number')
            ->add('patient', PatientType::class)
            ->add('patientSample', PatientSampleType::class);
    }
```

PatientOrderController

```
    {
        $patientOrder = new PatientOrder();

        $form = $this->createForm(PatientOrderType::class, $patientOrder);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            $patientOrder = $form->getData();

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($patientOrder);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('patient_order_index');
   }
```

Patient class

```
class Patient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PatientOrder", 
     *   mappedBy="patient")
     */
    public $patientOrders;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PatientSample", 
     * mappedBy="patient")
     */
    public $patientSamples;
```

PatientOrder Class

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Patient", 
     *  inversedBy="patientOrders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected  $patient;


/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PatientSample", 
     *inversedBy="patientOrders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $patientSample;
```

PatientSample class

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Patient", 
     * inversedBy="patientSamples")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $patient;

   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PatientOrder", 
     * mappedBy="patientSample")
     */
    private $patientOrders;
```

My expectations are that when the user clicks the save button it will insert 3 new rows into 3 separate tables in the database. Instead I'm getting SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'patient_id' cannot be null

Comment: please provide us with the shortened definitions of `Patient`, `PatientSample` and `PatientOrder` (only associations, their mappings, fields and setters are relevant here).

Comment: @Jakumi added the fields I thought might be relevant to this issue. If that's not enough information please let me know and I'll add anything you need.

Comment: that appears to be alright, the persist cascade should take care of everything when the `PatientOrder` is persisted. however, you seem to assume that the error is triggered by the `PatientOrder`'s `patient_id` field. your code *might* suggest, that the `PatientSample` - if it's actually an entity - might have a `patient_id` field as well which might not be connected to a patient yet (hence missing it's value -> null). So I guess, I want to ask, if there's a `PatientSample` entity and if so, what are the associations for it

Comment: Ah, I see. `Patient` has a OneToMany relationship with `PatientSample` so the `PatientSample` class has a `Patient` field and vice versa - I'll update the code with that information.

Comment: one last piece missing is probably the association between `PatientOrder` and `PatientSample`? but I already see that my assumption in my last comment is probably the reason...

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspicion. I believe you have to set the patient on your PatientSample (see answer ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay. So the problem is the following:

`Patient` is an independent entity, which is good. It has two associations, one with each `PatientSample` and `PatientOrder`. `PatientSample` and `PatientOrder` also have an association

Your form creates a new `PatientOrder`, that is automatically associated with the `Patient`, since `PatientOrder` is the owning side of that association, and also automatically persisted, due to the `cascade="PERSIST"` in the mapping.

`PatientOrder` also is automatically associated with the `PatientSample`, which you probably marked as cascade persisted as well. **However, the `patient` property/association of the `PatientSample` is not automatically set**, as far as I can see. That is at least *a* problem, if not *the* problem. - This luckily is a small problem, since it only creates a triangle in your dependency graph, however - since Patient is independent, it doesn't create a cycle (that would be a big problem). However, your form isn't *easily* capable of setting those kinds of dependencies, especially since they're not obvious. Technically, the sample could belong to another patient... (see validation comment at the end of answer)

#### the easy solution: set it explicitly

There are probably several solutions, the easiest, but not the best:

```
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        $patientOrder = $form->getData();
        // NEW! However, I don't know if this violates the Law of Demeter:
        $patientOrder->getSample()->setPatient($patientOrder->getPatient());

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($patientOrder);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('patient_order_index');
    }
```

the cleaner way would be to do this somewhere in a form event though...

#### adding a [form event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) handler (instead)

you should adapt the `PatientOrderType` code to something like this:

```
// be aware you need to set the following use clauses:
// use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
// use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

$builder
   // ...
   ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
         $patientOrder = $event->getData(); // view data, i.e. your objects
         $patientSample = $patientOrder->getPatientSample();
         if(!$patientSample->getPatient()) { 
             $patientSample->setPatient($patientOrder->getPatient());
         }
   })
;
```

This approach is somewhat tame. You could potentially also throw an exception if `$patientSample` already has a *different* Patient assigned (a form can be pre-filled/pre-set with entities). However, this approach will set a missing patient, which avoids the form leaving a `PatientSample` without a `Patient`.

why do this in a form event instead of directly setting it in the controller? because this way the form type is reusable without remembering "oh, i have to explicitly set the person on the PersonSample with this form type".

#### bonus: adding validation

for [validating](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) that a patient sample belongs to a patient order for the *same* patient, you could add the following [Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) constraint on the `PatientOrder` (the entity, not the form type):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(...)
 * @Assert\Expression("this.getPatientSample().getPatient() == this.getPatient()",
      message="PatientOrder's patient must be PatientSample's patient")
 */
class PatientOrder {...}
```

or a callback constraint and essentially do the same ... actually it feels weird to write code in an annotation (IDEs on average won't be of much help)

**update**: mixed up patient order and patient sample in validation part

Comment: Thank you @jakumi this got me to the next step which I believe is the same issue but with the user id which is in the `PatienSample` entity. I think with your information here though I can figure it out.

Comment: @BrianBarrick yeah, once you know what to look for, it's easier ;o) good luck!

Comment: If you have a source such as a blog or anything that I could learn more from on this, such as handling it in a form event, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @BrianBarrick I have added some more links and comments at the bottom

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help. I spent more time than I want to admit trying to figure this out and I wasn't even close. :)